# How to Clean an input field value using jquery?

Tags: jquery

This time I need help to complete my script, 
I got this table in my HTML page

```
<div class="Productos">
    <table id="products" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="left">Prod</th>
                <th>
                    <center>Desc</center>
                </th>
                <th>qty</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:popUp2('some_link_here','700','400');"><input type="text" name="f_prod_id" size="10" value="5060102" readonly></td>
                <td class="left">desc1</a></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="f_qty" min="1" max="9999" step="1">
                </td>
                <td>35.17</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:popUp2('some_link_here','700','400');"><input type="text" name="f_prod_id" size="10" value="5060101" readonly></td>
                <td class="left">desc2</a></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="f_qty" min="1" max="9999" step="1">
                </td>
                <td>18.48</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I need to do is to clean the value of the item `f_qty`. I am using the following syntax to get it done:

```
$('#f_qty').val('');
```

But it does not work. In my HTML screen, my old values are still there. Any suggestions?

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Totalizar</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#Calculate").click(
    // move value
    function () {
        $("input[name=f_qty]").each(function () {
            var valueInCurrentTextBox = $(this).val();
            var productId = $(this).find(".f_prod_id").text();

            if (valueInCurrentTextBox != '') {
                $("#P23_qty").val(valueInCurrentTextBox);
                alert('codid : ' + (productId));
                $('#f_qty').val('');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="totals"></div>
<p style="clear: both;">
<button type="button" style="font-weight: bold; width: auto;" id="Calculate">Agregar Productos</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f_qty` is not the `id`, it's the `name` of the inputs. Therefore, you need to use an attribute selector rather than an id selector.

```
$('[name="f_qty"]').val('');
```

I also noticed that you are already looping over elements using this selector, so you could simply use `$(this).val('')`

Additionnaly, `var productId = $(this).find(".f_prod_id").text();` is quite wierd since `this` in the function provided to `each` will be an `input` element and input elements cannot contain children elements.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting using name,

```
$('[name="f_qty"]').val('');
```

or

```
$('input[name="f_qty"]').val('');
```

`#` is an id selector, I mean if your id would have been f_qty, you should use `$('#f_qty')`.